# Optimization problem - vector mapping

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics

`A` and `B` are sets of `N` dimensional vectors (`N=10`), `|B|>=|A|` (`|A|=10^2`, `|B|=10^5`). Similarity measure sim(a,b) is dot product (required). The task is following: for each vector `a` in `A` find vector `b` in `B`, such that sum of similarities `ss` of all pairs is maximal.

My first attempt was greedy algorithm:

1. find the pair with the highest similarity and remove that pair from A,B
2. repeat (1) until A is empty

But such greedy algorithm is suboptimal in this case:

```
a_1=[1, 0]
a_2=[.5, .4]

b_1=[1, 1]
b_2=[.9, 0]

sim(a_1,b_1)=1
sim(a_1,b_2)=.9
sim(a_2,b_1)=.9
sim(a_2, b_2)=.45
```

Algorithm returns `[a_1,b_1]` and `[a_2, b_2]`, `ss=1.45`, but optimal solution yields `ss=1.8`.

Is there efficient algo to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Please tag as homework if appropriate....

Comment: Intuition tells me that you won't find an algorithm faster than *O(|A||B|)* worst-case.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth You might've misunderstood the problem. *Correct* `O(|A||B|)` algorithm would be very much welcome here :)

Comment: @Nikita: After a second read, yes, you're right!  I have misunderstood the problem...  please ignore me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a [matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_matching) in weighted [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). Just assume that weight function `f` is a dot product (`|ab|`).
I don't think the special structure of your weight function will simplify problem a lot, so you're pretty much down to finding a maximum matching.

You can find some basic algorithms for this problem [in this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_matching#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs). Although at first glance they don't seem viable for your data (`V = 10^5`, `E = 10^7`), I would still research them: some of them might allow you to take advantage of your 'lame' set of vertixes, with one part orders of magnitude smaller than the other.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) also seems relevant, although doesn't list any algorithms.

Not exactly a solution, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I second Nikita here, it is an assignment (or matching) problem. I'm not sure this is computationally feasible for your problem, but you could use the Hungarian algorithm, also known as [Munkres' assignment algorithm](http://csclab.murraystate.edu/bob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html), where the cost of assignment `(i,j)` is the negative of the dot product of `ai` and `bj`. Unless you happen to know how the elements of A and B are formed, I think this is the most efficient known algorithm for your problem.

Comment: "Unless you happen to know how the elements of A and B are formed" - can you please explain how this knowledge could be exploited?